# Chaining PCA9685 boards

Tags: esp32

following on-line guidance

I have three PCA9685 boards 'chained' to drive 40 SG90 servos.  All appears fine except that nothing connected to the second board works?

As is required I carefully bridged A0 for board2 and then A1 for board3 to make addresses 41 and 42.   I have even adapted an additional board for board2 to check my soldering!

I am using standard instructions i.e.:

```
Adafruit_PWMServoDriver board1 = Adafruit_PWMServoDriver(0x40);
Adafruit_PWMServoDriver board2 = Adafruit_PWMServoDriver(0x41);
Adafruit_PWMServoDriver board3 = Adafruit_PWMServoDriver(0x42);
```

Then later :

```
board1.begin();
board1.setPWMFreq(60); // Analog servos run at ~60 Hz updates
board2.begin();
board2.setPWMFreq(60);
board3.begin();
board3.setPWMFreq(60);
```

Then later a typical routine to cycle all servos.  Code has many print lines as I check that is producing the right outcomes..

```
if (allServo){
 for (int angle = servoAngleMin; angle <= servoAngleMax; angle 
 += servoStep)
 {
  Serial.println("ALL SERVOS");
  for (int i = 0; i < 40; i++)
  {
   board1.setPWM(i, 0, angleToPulse(angle));
   board2.setPWM(i, 0, angleToPulse(angle));
   board3.setPWM(i, 0, angleToPulse(angle));
  }
  delay(100);
  Serial.println("All Servo delay");
 }
```

This segment correctly moves all the servos on boards 1 and 3 but nothing on board2.  I have tried it with explicit position values just as a check and I have variously commented out the board1 and board3 sections as well as other attempts to isolate and check the routines.

I have checked voltages of the external power source attached to each board etc and the wiring in general.

It seems that the 'middle' board2 receives the same inputs (using serial prints confirm what is being sent) as the other two.

What might be wrong and where and what should I look at?

All suggestions gratefully received!

Comment: What happens if you disconnect board1 and board3 and only connect board2? Does it work? Also please post a [minimal, reproducible example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_reproducible_example) - complete code that demonstrates the problem. It could be something as simple as a typo in the code you decided not to share.

Comment: Thanks for your attention.  Yes I have done this.  I have also connected some board2 servos to board1 and 3 to check that they haven't suffered some collective damage.I have varied the connections to board2 including directly from esp32 to check connections.  I have forensically checked the salient sections of the code all of which are essentially the same except for the board reference.  I have explicitly referenced the servos rather than relying on counters etc etc etc.

Comment: Could it be some firmware type or other corruption?  The Adafruit library is potentially very complex re changing timing and voltage levels.  I am loathe to start fiddling with instructions that I don't really understand.  Is there a simple refresh routine for instance for the boards or the i2c on esp32?

Comment: I have added code snippets above.